# Magento 2.3 is not running under windows 10 with PHP Version 7.2.13

Tags: magento2.3, windows

Magento 2.3 is not running under windows 10 with PHP Version 7.2.13.

[image]

[image]

Comment: set domain `127.0.0.1/mage23` remove `cache` folder from `var\cache` and run command from CLI `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

This is a path issue. 
try editing the Validator file from **`vendor`** folder with namespace

> **magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File**

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then **cache:flush**

Check if it works

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact solution if it exist after changing the

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

ADD to the `database`:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Thank you,